# keras custom sigmoid adding bias

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras

There is a need to add bias to my custom sigmod function and apply this as a last activation layer in NN. But my recall goes rightly into 1. That shows me that something is wrong with the formula.

**Custom sigmoid function**

[image]

**Recall goes strictly into 1**

[image]

```
def custom_sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + K.exp(-20*x - 0.5))
```

At the same time, custom sigmoid without multiplier and bias works great.

```
def custom_sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + K.exp(x))
```

as can be seen here

[image]

```
self.model_.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=custom_sigmoid))
self.model_.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=[precision_threshold(0.7), recall_threshold(0.7)])
```

How to modify the custom sigmoid function to make it work?

Comment: The code to implement that formula seems to be right, and the issue seems to lie in the custom sigmoid function. That seems in line with your `_How to modify the custom sigmoid function to make it work?_` request. However, A) this is a ***programming*** Q&A site, not a mathematics one, so I don't know if we can help. B) Even if we tried, how are we supposed to know how to add "bias"? That is incredibly too vague.

Comment: @wundermahn The idea is not in math part but in how keras applies custom activation function inside. All works fine but not in Keras, so the question is more in programming part. I suppose that somehow I didn't right passed this function to keras but I don't know exactly what problem with. But anyway, thanks for the reply

Comment: @IvanShelonik I am not necessarily sure what you mean by bias in your explanation, but if you examine the plot of the custom function you've implemented it has a very steep and short transition region. This is going to make it very difficult for the network to "learn"; tune the network weights. I think this may be directly related to ArronCao's answer too. You will most likely get some under/overflow when working with this function because of how steep and short its transition is. // Why are you attempting to alter function in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula has no apparent problem, but it's likely to cause arithmetic overflow for `-20*x - 0.5`, can you check the range of `x`. For example, if x is in `[-100, 100]`, the original sigmoid won't overflow while your customized sigmoid will. You can do a simple experiment in numpy:

```
import numpy as np

def original_sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(x))


def custom_sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-20 * x - 0.5))


x = np.linspace(-100, 100)
print(original_sigmoid(x)) 
print(custom_sigmoid(x)) # this will output a warning: "RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp"
```